# Request Entity Too Large / 404 ErrorDocument Joomla 3.3.6

Tags: php, apache, joomla3.0, whm, dedicated-server

I have the problem when I upload large files, I have a server dedicated, when upload files more than 500Mb. I have edit the PHP Configuration Editor on my Panel WHM.

```
post_max_size 3000M
upload_max_filesize 3000M
max_input_time -1
memory_limit 700M
max_execution_time 9000
```

error:

```
Request Entity Too Large

The requested resource
/index.php
does not allow request data with GET requests, or the amount of data provided in the request exceeds the capacity limit.
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

After making these settings, joomla ignored, especially the extension that I'm using. "Music Collection". The settings that this extension take is the default. 2MB by file, 8MB max post.

Recently I am using an SSL cetificado, could this be another reason?

Does anyone know how to fix this? Sorry my english is little bad.

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try to setup LimitRequestBody directive in your httpd.conf file or a local .htaccess file

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody